# How to create smooth strokes with the Grease Pencil?

Tags: grease-pencil

The strokes I drew with the grease pencil are jagged.

[image]

How can I draw smooth strokes with the grease pencil in Blender 2.82?

Comment: There are anti-aliasing issues in 2.82. please update to 2.83 or, even better 2.9.